# GCP VM showing different CPU usage in web and mobile app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

In mobile app usage peak is 90% whereas in website usage of same VM at same time is 150%.

[image: CPU usage in web]

[image: CPU usage in Mobile app]

Comment: In one screensot you are looking at a 15min window, in the other it is 8 days. Try to look at graphs when conditions are more similar.

Answer (score 1):

As @DanyL mentioned, you are not using the same time windows:

- The web screenshot is showing a 1h time window: for which the **alignment period** is **1min** (by default)
- The mobile screenshot is showing 7 or 8 days windows: for which the **alignment period** is **1h** (by default)

For CPU Utilization, the aligner function is mean by default, so if you take the values of your 1h window (with peek of 150%) and calculate the mean it will be around 90%. This explains the 90% you are seeing in the second screen. For more information about aggregation, alignment, aligners check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/aggregation)